# Ability to Edit Google Sheets' Custom Function Result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering if it is possible to edit the result of a custom function in Google Sheets when returning a 2-dimensional array.

If I try to delete a cell that is part of the returned array, it blinks but stays there.

If I enter something in a cell that is part of the returned 2-dimensional array, it works, but the function then does not return because the value is blocking the display of the 2-dimensional array (Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A3.)

Comment: This is not possible without copy-pasting the values over the range which makes it static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as for built-in functions returning an array (`split`, `importrange`, `query`, etc): output cannot be edited. But there is a workaround described below.

Suppose the output range is `A1:B6`. Elsewhere in a sheet, enter `=A1` and copy this formula to a 2 by 6 range. This creates a range that is visually identical to the function output, but editable cell-by-cell. If you edit a cell in this new range, it will cease to depend on the function, but the rest will still be updated if the function input changes.

Comment: Great! Thanks. The cell also still gets updated when the function result changes if you keep the reference like so =A1 and just add something (for example =A1 + 2).